# After first C# request through the ssh tunnel , second request stack on GetResponse, but browser requests work

Tags: c#, firefox, ssh, eof, tunnel

I creating SSH tunnel with this library  : https://sshnet.codeplex.com/

Tunnel works fine, if enter url in firefox like : `http://localhost:10000/somefile.js`

It is always returned. But if i request it from the console aplication after first reqeust in ouput appear

```
SshNet.Logging Verbose: 1 : SendMessage to server 'ChannelDataMessage': 'SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA : #0'.
SshNet.Logging Verbose: 1 : ReceiveMessage from server: 'ChannelDataMessage': 'SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA : #0'.
SshNet.Logging Verbose: 1 : ReceiveMessage from server: 'ChannelEofMessage': 'SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_EOF : #0'.
SshNet.Logging Verbose: 1 : SendMessage to server 'ChannelEofMessage': 'SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_EOF : #0'.
SshNet.Logging Verbose: 1 : SendMessage to server 'ChannelCloseMessage': 'SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_CLOSE : #0'.
SshNet.Logging Verbose: 1 : ReceiveMessage from server: 'ChannelCloseMessage': 'SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_CLOSE : #0'.
```

and after

'SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_EOF : #0'.

the code stucks here:

```
response = request.GetResponse();
```

and then time out.

here is my complete code:

```
        connectionInfo = new PrivateKeyConnectionInfo(domain, name, new PrivateKeyFile(File.OpenRead(keyPath), pass));
          using (client = new SshClient(connectionInfo)) {
            client.ErrorOccurred += client_ErrorOccurred;
            client.Connect();
            port = new ForwardedPortLocal(boundHost, boundPort, remoteHost, remotePort);           
            client.AddForwardedPort(port);
            port.Exception += port_Exception;
            port.Start();

            //This request successfully returned but after this output shows SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_EOF
            SendRequest();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            // And in this Request is code stacked on get response
            SendRequest();

        // Request Call 
        void SendRequest(){
        string url = "http://localhost:10000/somefile.js";
        WebResponse response = null;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0";
        request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.Timeout = 15000;

        // Here its stacked after 2 request

        response = request.GetResponse();

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        response.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(stream);
        stream.Position = 0;
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string bssResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(bssResponse.Substring(0, 20));
```

So where could be difference between call from firefox and from console app ?

Requests from firefox invoke in tunnel output openning and closing of channel but not EOF

I tryed to check it with fiddler so i made everything like in firefox but it still doesnt work

When i create this tunnel by putty - console app works.

Thanks for any help or suggestion.

Comment: Most of the time this occurs when you are asking for bytes while there are none. It will block until there are new bytes.

Comment: Well i requesting for script which is returned in the first request , and also is returned everytime if i request it from browser so there are some bytes

Answer (score 0):

After two days of searching i found it !! request was stacked on the port and channel wasnt close becouse i forget to set

```
request.KeepAlive = false;
```

I hope this will help somebody